# Trying to make script only send a message to teams if specific value returned

Tags: function, powershell

I can login, get the API token from the server, and return the values I'm looking for. What I haven't been able to do is make the script write to the host only if the value returned is NOT "Primary".

I'm not quite to sending an alert to MS Teams yet as I'm building this modular as I go.

Right now, the code always writes "fail" to the host regardless of the value I set. I had originally put a simple If -not match statement within the CAStatus function, but I don't want to build my alert function within the function I'm using to retrieve server status

```
#Use login token to pull CA system status
Function CAStatus {
#URL and logon token in header
$system_summary_uri ="https://website.com"
$header_parameters = @{"Authorization" = CALogon}

#Get Summary info from primary CA server and only return its role 
(Primary or DR)
$summary_query = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $system_summary_uri -Method Get - 
Headers $header_parameters -ContentType "application/json"
$summary_result = $summary_query.Vaults.Role[0]
return $summary_result
}

#Report if primary server fails
Function Notify {
if (CAStatus -eq "dr") {
    Write-Host "fail"
}
}

castatus
```

I expect output of "fail" only when the value returned by the API call to CAStatus is "DR". Otherwise I want it to do nothing.

Right now, when I run CAStatus, I get the value "Primary" returned, which is correct since the server is currently in the primary role. There should be nothing output to the host since CAStatus does not equal "dr", but it is outputting "fail" anyway.

Comment: You are breaking code lines in a haphazard way. Also, in the Function CAStatus, I don't see you calling the function Notify anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean haphazard way? Seems like it’s broken up by function performed with the logon piece omitted. Also, posted this part after messing with it more, but I was calling the Notify function to run it. I ended up fixing it by assigning CAStatus to a variable and substituting that variable for CAstatus in the Notify function. Now I’m wondering why I couldn’t just pass CAStatus directly into Notify like I have in the code I posted and had to instead assign it to a variable to make this work.

Comment: Haphazard because yoou insert newlines in places where they definitively should not be. Like in `-Method Get - `**<ENTER>**`Headers` and `return its role `**<ENTER>**`(Primary or DR)`. Anyway, if you want to use the _Result_ of the function `CAStatus` directly inside the `if{..}`, you should wrap it inside brackets like `if ((CAStatus) -eq "dr") {`.